# TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database-cursor

I get this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

when I try to execute:

```
reply = db['test'].find({"date":{"$gt":date_query}} ,{"date":1,"route_id":1,"loc":1,"_id":0})

length = len(reply)
```

Comment: this is because all you did was define the cursor which is a query request for the server - you didn't actually get a set of results back (because normally you would iterate over a cursor getting batches of documents at a time).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [pymongo cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html) has a method `count()` which will return what you're looking for:

```
reply = db['test'].find(
  {"date":{"$gt":date_query}},
  {"date":1,"route_id":1,"loc":1,"_id":0}
)

length = reply.count()
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, count will do the work for you.

```
length = reply.count()
```

or

```
length = reply.count(with_limit_and_skip=False)
```

had to suffer a lot coz  length = count(reply) also did not work. Since I'm not allowed to comment yet, thought to leave this answer. Hope this will help somebody to save some time.

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Mongo 4.0.3`/`PyMongo 3.7.0`, you could alternatively use [`count_documents`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.7.2/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=count#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) instead of `count` on a `cursor`:

```python
db.collection.count_documents({ "a": 2 })
# where { "a": 2 } is whatever filtering query
```

`db.collection.count_documents` is the alternative to the now deprecated [`db.collection.count`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.7.2/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=count#pymongo.collection.Collection.count).

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:
`count` is deprecated. Use `reply.explain().get("executionStats", {}).get("nReturned")`

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain

I'm updating this thread since I was searching for this answer.

You will also see answers telling you to do `len(list(reply))`. This is of course not recommended since it loads all documents at once in memory. Advantages of cursors is to load each document only when needed, and not to keep it in memory if it is useless. For instance, in my usecase, putting it in a list makes my jupyter kernel explode.

Comment: as of September the 9th 2023, "This is the way"!

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying on MySQL;

```
len(results.fetchall())
```